# MailChimp White Text Template Issue

Tags: css, templates, mailchimp

I'm having a little difficulty with a MailChimp template I have recently made.

It has been fully tested and works fine, the only issues comes when the clients is editing the text in the editor. The text colour is supposed to be white but the trouble is, then background colour of the MailChimp editor is white so it doesn't "appear" for the client easily.

Comment: So what is the question? Need to change the theme of the template editor?

Comment: can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: @Donte'Trumble Pretty much. As typing with white text on a white background is quite tricky.

I personally would have thought MailChimp wouldn't style the text until it's in the template itself.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to set a background colour on the `table` or `td` ?

Comment: Thanks @NickR but it's the MailChimp editor it's that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys but I have resolved this issue!

It was a case of adding a background colour to the property which in turn applies this to MailChimps editor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that solution @James?

Answer (score 1):

I had and resolved the same issue -> the white text was on a white background in the editor.

To resolve:
I simply had to ensure the 'background' style was set to !important in my code

This then ensured this same style was also shown in the Mailchimp editor

e.g.

```
#mybutton {background: #000 !important; color: #fff !important}
```